# ArrayList does not give the get option to retrieve the data

Tags: java, arraylist

I create customer and computer arraylist from the existing cutomer and computer classes as belows

```
ArrayList<Customer> customer = new ArrayList<Customer>();

ArrayList<Computer> computer = new ArrayList<Computer>();
```

But I don't available to get option to retrieve the data. Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: `But I don't available to get option to retrieve the data` I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: seriously, read [arrayList documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) first

Comment: I mean I cannot retrieve items in arrey list because of it dosent give me get(customer.get(index))

Comment: It si better to use List<computer>=new ArrayList<computer>

Answer (score 2):

`customer.get(i)` i is the index.

```
computer.get(i)
```

You have get like this.

Comment: Yeah true. But I don't have get option for the created arraylist

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS METHOD AS SPECIFIED HERE. Read up on this stuff please! 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

get(int index)
Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

Answer (score -1):

For Customer : 
`Customer ithCustomer = customer.get(i);(retrieve ith item in the customer list)`